# How to create reusable function with alternating if statements

Tags: javascript, css, algorithm, math

I am creating a smooth scrolling and a bounce (at top and bottom) effect. (After a full day of trial and error,) I was able to successfully implement it. I'm now having trouble finding a method to have reusable clean code. (I think that's called an algorithm?)

The specific problem I'm having, is alternating between `<=` and `>=`. The code overall can use some clean up, which I did to the best of my ability, but I think it needs some more (let me know if it doesn't).

So in reusable `function`, like this:

```
function reusableFunction() {
    ...
    if (num1 >= num2) // One case I have to compare like this
    if (num1 <= num2) // Another case, I have to compare like this
    ...
}
```

I got stuck at line #86 in the `function bounceBack`. If you have a better way of making the smooth scrolling, and bouncing effect, please post as an answer. I don't want to use any librarys, or other frameworks (like JQuery).

#### JSFiddle

```js
console.clear();

var innerWrapper = document.getElementById('innerWrapper');
innerWrapper.addEventListener('mousewheel', handleScroll);
innerWrapper.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)';

var interval, // scroll is being eased
  mult = 0, // how fast do we scroll
  dir = 0, // 1 = scroll down, -1 = scroll up
  steps = 50, // how many steps in animation
  length = 30; // how long to animate

var bouncePadding = 30;

function handleScroll(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  clearInterval(interval); // cancel previous animation
  ++mult; // we are going to scroll faster
  var delta = -Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
  if (dir != delta) { // scroll direction changed
    mult = 1; // start slowly
    dir = delta;
  }
  var start = parseInt(innerWrapper.style.transform.split(',')[1], 10); // Get x from translate3d
  var end = start + length * mult * delta; // where to end the scroll
  var change = end - start; // base change in one step
  var step = 0; // current step
  var scrolledToBottom = innerWrapper.scrollHeight - innerWrapper.parentElement.offsetHeight;
  var tempVar;

  interval = setInterval(function() {
    var scrollPosition = easeOut(step++, start, -change, steps);
    scrollPosition = clamp(scrollPosition, -scrolledToBottom - bouncePadding, 0 + bouncePadding);
    innerWrapper.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + scrollPosition + 'px, 0px)';
    if (tempVar === scrollPosition) {
      step = steps;
    } else {
      tempVar = scrollPosition
    }

    if (step >= steps) { // scroll finished without speed up - stop by easing out
      endScrollCallback();

      if (scrollPosition > 0 && dir === -1) {
        step = 0;
        var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
          var scrollPos = easeOut(step++, scrollPosition, -scrollPosition, 15);
          innerWrapper.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + (scrollPos) + 'px, 0px)';

          if (scrollPos <= 0) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            innerWrapper.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + (0) + 'px, 0px)';
          }
        }, 10);
      } else if (scrollPosition < -scrolledToBottom && dir === 1) {
        step = 0;
        var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
          var change = -scrolledToBottom - scrollPosition;
          var scrollPos = easeOut(step++, scrollPosition, change, 15);
          innerWrapper.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + (scrollPos) + 'px, 0px)';

          if (scrollPos >= -scrolledToBottom) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            innerWrapper.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + (-scrolledToBottom) + 'px, 0px)';
          }
        }, 10);
      }
    }
  }, 10);
}

function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
  t /= d;
  return -c * t * (t - 2) + b;
}

function endScrollCallback() {
  mult = 0;
  clearInterval(interval);
}

function bounceBack(from, to, difference) {
  var step = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var scrollPos = outQuartic(step++, from, difference, 15);
    innerWrapper.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + (scrollPos) + 'px, 0px)';
    if (scrollPos <= 0) { /* Got stuck here */
      clearInterval(interval);
      innerWrapper.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + to + 'px, 0px)';
    }
  }, 10);
}

function clamp(val, min, max) {
  if (typeof min !== 'number') min = 0;
  if (typeof max !== 'number') max = 1;
  return Math.min(Math.max(val, min), max);
}
```

```css
body {} #outerWrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}
#content {
  background-image: url("http://images.freeimages.com/images/premium/previews/3037/30376024-beautiful-flower-portrait.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
  <div id="innerWrapper">
    <div id="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
      sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus
      Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus
      enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar
      justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames
      ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque
      Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem
      lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie
      vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum
      vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque
      Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci
      Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla.
      Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet
      risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat
      Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor
      dolor
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The opposite of `>=` is `<`.

Comment: Please say more about what you'd like `reusableFunction` to do, such as any arguments , conditions and return value/s. Also what specifically are you stuck on, where you commented, "stuck here" ?

Comment: @גלעדברקן That's the specific place I'm stuck at. But the overall code I think can use some cleanup. I want `bounceBack` to be reusable for the two if statements inside the `if (step >= steps) {` statement. And possible for the regular smooth scrolling as well.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I understand that, but how would I implement a reusable function for the `bounceBack` function, which in one case (of the function being used) will have `>=`, and in another will have `<=`?

Comment: If you want someone to review and comment on your code, consider submitting it on code review.

Comment: @torazaburo Before I posted the question, I wasn't sure if I should post it on Stackoverflow, or code review. The reason I chose here, is because I needed help with the algorithm, and the if statement. But I probably should have broken the question down to two, and asked one stackoverflow, and the other at code review. But thanks for the comment!

Comment: note that you can only submit it there if your code does as you expect. just noting because the wording of your question indicates that you're missing something

Comment: @DanPantry Thanks! I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, to customize a function, which is what `<=` is, one can use a function. If you'd like customize a statement like:

```
if (a <someFunction> b){
  // ...
}
```

where `someFunction` in your case can be either `<=` or `>`, one way to do it could be:

```
function f(a,b,conditionsMet){
  return conditionsMet ? a <= b : a > b;
}
```

and then call it:

```
if ( f(a,b,are conditions met?) ){
  // ...
}
```

(Not sure if that's what you mean, feel free to comment..)

Comment: avoid using `boolean` as it's reserved.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is, there's a variable in `bounceBack` that I'm comparing either `>=` or `<=`. So I can't pass a parameter `bounceBack` with a set `bool`. It's hard to explain, but I hope you understood.

Comment: @Jessica thank you for your comment. What you describe seems to me like what I addressed. To help us understand, please state (1) under which conditions you would use `>=` and which conditions `<=`; and (2) which variables you'll compare with the correct comparator (`>=` or `<=`). For example, in the line you commented about getting stuck, the variables being compared are `scrollPos` and `0` - these would correspond with `a` and `b` in my answer; but I can't find where you describe the condition for using `>=` or `<=` - those conditions would fit as the third parameter in my example answer.

Comment: Oh. I get it now. Thanks! .אגב , אני יהודי. והשם שלי, שמחה I would be interested in hearing more about you. You can email me at simchaCahn(at)gmail.com